# Using ui dialog buttons

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I have dialogs on my pages which apply the ui dialog button set, i use this code

```
$('#pop_div').load("mypopname.php").dialog({
        width: 880,
        height: 650,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'page title',
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $('#pop_div').dialog("close");
            },
            Submit: function () {
                $("#frmname").submit();
            }
        }
    });
```

I was wondering is it possible to use the same buttons (theme) normally in any page (not necessarily in a dialog) ??

Comment: Just copy the stylesheet for that particular class and add it in your stylesheet

Comment: its not that simple I think, the theme is all about creating divs and spans around the element to give it the popular shape.

Comment: Dude. Read documentation. Go to http://jqueryui.com/ and there's a gaggle of gunk there to grep, Sherlock. You can do everything to your hearts content without having to write custom css and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<button>A button</button>
<input type="submit" value="A submit button" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('button').button();
$('input[type=submit]').button();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesnt apply the dialog buttons theme to it